# Dynamic link extraction

Tags: android, firebase-dynamic-links

I have the following link when clicking launches my android app.

https://example.app.goo.gl/?link=https://whatever.com/customers?id=MTgy&token=MTI2MzI1M&apn=com/foo.bar&isi=1045116743&ibi=com.foo.bar&efr=1

In the Activity, I can get https://whatever.com/customers?id=MTgy (using  `FirebaseDynamicLinks`). But how do I get the entire original link?

Answer (score 2):

```
// [START get_deep_link] in OnCreate() method
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
            .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
            .addOnSuccessListener(this,this) //implement OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData> for this
            .addOnFailureListener(this,this); // implement OnFailureListener for this




   @Override
   public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
    // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
    Uri deepLink = null;
    if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
        deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
    }
    // Handle the deep link. For example, open the linked
    // content, or apply promotional credit to the user's
    // account.
    // ...

    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    // Display deep link in the UI
    if (deepLink != null) {
        //now you have your dynamicLink here in Uri object
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "getDynamicLink: no link found");
    }
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
   }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e);
  }
```

What you can get from link is this only now perform action what do you want to perform

Comment: Not what I asked for. I want to get whole the link from within the Activity. Only  https://whatever.com/customers?id=MTgy  is passed in intent data.

Comment: can you please specify what is your full dynamic url and what do you want.

Comment: You are not understanding what I asked for. Say you have scheme://example.com?link=scheme://example.org . When you click it, the app opens and in the code you have pasted above `pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink() ` will hold scheme://example.org . I want to get the entire `scheme://example.com?link=scheme://example.org` in the activity, not just the redirected part! Hope I am clear this time.

Comment: Dear @AayushKarki in PendingIntent you can receive only link parameter of Dynamic link

Comment: you can also get link without getting Firebase object just put `Intent appLinkIntent = getIntent();
        String appLinkAction = appLinkIntent.getAction();
        Uri appLinkData = appLinkIntent.getData();`  in your mainActivity.java onCreate() method

Comment: Are you sure that there is no way to get the original link?? :(

Comment: Yes dear you can get only link attribute from your DynamicLink.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158394/discussion-between-rutvik-bhatt-and-aayush-karki).